Exclude property from response but not from Serialization
I have object that has several properties that shouldn't be returned in API response. However, I am using JsonSerialize on this object for other stuffs (storing on backend side) and I need those properties to be serialized. I cannot create new classes to exclude these properties because that will take a lot of time, since the codebase is huge. Is there any other way I can exclude properties from being returned in response, but still be serialized when I need them?

How are you excluding the properties now?

"I cannot create new classes to exclude these properties because that will take a lot of time" - Too bad. That's exactly what you will be doing and should have in the first place. Anything that circumvents that will take up at least just as much time.

I am not excluding them, they are returned in response now, but that is causing some other issues. There are over 30 such classes, and I can't just create new ones, because that will require changing new methods and probably other bugs will be produced.

I am confident that yes, you can. Unless you present an example that shows the exact problem. In which case I would say you are pretty much stuck in a dead-end one-way street ...

@chessGeek: You could potentially use different JSON serializers for your different use cases, one of which makes use of attributes to ignore specified properties while those attributes aren't used by the other serializer.  You could also write your own serializer which makes use of any options/attributes/etc. that you like.

Going along David's suggestion, source generated serializers might be an option. But there, too, I would consider a significant amount of time that will have to be invested.

trust me @Fildor, that is legacy code, there are 30+ classes, which are also used as NuGet packages, that will affect several projects, it is bad idea to touch these.. it can be costly, since it is directly related to money

Awwwhhh, ... what did you do to deserve this? ;D What C#/.Net versions are we talking then? Newer versions might present more options... So, I won't insist any further - been there, done that. But: in the long run, I would highly recommend to fix the design - unrelated to if we find a short-term way out for you.

net 6.0. Well, I understand you, but since it is critical to make any major changes, I would rather keep my job :D There are some hints from my colleague, to use different serializer for API responses, but I am not sure how will I do it at the moment

Well, you could use Newtonsoft for one vector and System.Text.Json for the other. That way you can apply either Newtonsoft's "Ignore" Attribute or STJ's. Me personnally would consider this to be extremely hacky and brittle but if that's what will save your behind for now, then so be it.

Where I am not sure if that's actually applicable for you. You said something about they are published in NuGets ... are those public? Because then you don't really have control over which one will be used ... :(

=> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ombCEu would mean to introduce change to your entity classes.

I will try this, although it is changing entities, probably it will not affect to much

Try decorating your properties with [JsonIgnore] Attribute. This will hide that property from being sent via API.
And for your serialization need, instead of using NewtonSoft.Json use a different serialization library like System.Text.Serialization it will serialize your properties even if they are decorated with  [JsonIgnore].
